# Prevent ads from showing in background (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

so iv'e set my ad to show after every 5 minutes but the problem is that my app shows Ad even after my app is in background and i am using another app or just like keep the app at background.
I want my app Ads to stop showing after i put the app on background (My Ads don't show after i close app which is fine, but in background it still does)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {


            MobileAds.initialize(this,
                    "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347551713");
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940255099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            prepareAD();
            ScheduledExecutorService ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                                mInterstitialAd.show();
                            } else {
                                Log.d("TAG", "Ad not loaded");
                            }
                            prepareAD();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection, please try again later...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public void prepareAD() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173212");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to showing the app in the main thread instead of some background thread. If you pass anything to check if the activity is alive inside the background thread then it has chances of memory leak.

Even if it's in the background then it will check for the activity state and will fail.

```
getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

using the life cycle component, do this.

```
ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        boolean stateAlive = getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
                        if (stateAlive && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Ad not loaded");
                        }
                        prepareAD();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```